# How to centralize the CVS server name for an Eclipse project-set (.psf)?

Tags: eclipse, cvs

We have users around the world who use the same source code. The location of the CVS repository (in the below sample: `cvsserver`) differs from one office to another. The project set file we have commited in CVS (for use by all users) looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<psf version="2.0">
<provider id="org.eclipse.team.cvs.core.cvsnature">
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:cvsserver:/topdir,Project1,Project1,BRANCH"/>
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:cvsserver:/topdir,Project2,Project2,BRANCH"/>
<project reference="1.0,:pserver:cvsserver:/topdir,Project3,Project3,BRANCH"/>
.... lots of other projects with the same "pserver:cvsserver:/topdir" part
</provider>
... several workingSets
</psf>
```

Users in the same office as me can checkout from this project-set ***as-is***. But for users in other offices, the cvs server name **is not `cvsserver`**... They have to find/replace **`cvsserver`** in the .psf file and then they can checkout the projects (using `Import-->Team-->Team Project Set` in Eclipse).

Is it possible to use a variable or property in Eclipse so that the user will set that variable once and for all and use the .psf file without modifying it?

Or as an alternative, can one declare the CVS server name at the top of the .psf file, so that the user will have to edit just that single declaration in the file?

Thanks in advance for any help, since I can't find that specific information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't see any support for anything like this in the `.psf` loading code (`org.eclipse.team.internal.ui.ProjectSetImporter` which uses `org.eclipse.team.internal.ccvs.ui.CVSProjectSetSerializer` for CVS).